# SQL Picking out dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables containing ID of a person, name of event, and the dates of the event occurrence. One table contains Event A and the other Event B, so I union-ed the two tables. The aim is to pick out the dates where Event A and B occur on the same day or within 5 days of each other:

```
ID        Date     Event
1234    1/6/2012    B
1234    1/6/2012    B
1234    1/6/2012    B
1234    1/6/2012    B
1234    9/26/2013   B
1234    9/26/2013   A
1234    9/26/2013   B
1234    9/26/2013   B
1234    9/26/2013   B
1234    1/13/2014   A
1234    1/13/2014   B
1234    3/20/2015   B
1234    3/20/2015   A
1234    12/21/2015  A
1234    4/12/2016   A
1234    4/12/2016   B
1234    1/3/2017    A
1234    1/3/2017    B
```

So I need the query to return:

```
 ID      Date
 1234   9/26/2013
 1234   1/13/2014
 1234   3/20/2015
 1234   4/12/2016
 1234   1/3/2017
```

If the following scenario happens, I need it to pick the earlier date (6/17/2015) and ignore 6/19/2015:

```
ID      Date       Event
5678    6/17/2015   A
5678    6/18/2015   B
5678    6/19/2015   A
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please list some of the queries you have tried to achieve this result.

Comment: Obviously, store dates using a date data type, in case you haven't done so already.

Comment: Also, you have several identical events occurring on the same day. With no means of distinuishing them, this problem is effectively insoluble.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what you try. As presented, the problem is insoluble.

Comment: First you should inform yourself about the creation of tables in DB, you need to have an unique key column in a table, to be able to distinguish each row of data, which it's not happening on your table, since your ID is always de same.. Read about it here --> http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/795/table-creation#t=20170412153231822323

Comment: And for more documentation about MySQL --> http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/topics

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the first scenario of your question where both events A and B occur on the same date.

```
SELECT id,date
  FROM 
    (    
        SELECT DISTINCT id,date,event
          FROM Yourtable
     )
GROUP BY id,date
HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN event = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN event = 'B' THEN 1 END ) = 2
```